# Как расшифровать ошибки Uncaught ReferenceError, Uncaught Error, Uncaught TypeError и т.д

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, как расшифровать данные ошибки по порядку? О чем говорит наличие этих ошибок?

[image: Ошибки]

Comment: Похоже на то, что вы накосячили с подключением jQuery (в ошибке 2 сообщается о том, что следует подключить jQuery до JavaScriptа). Если вы хотите получать более конкретный ответ, выложите код - не хотелось бы гадать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `GET` ошибка, браузер\скрипт, обращается к файлу на сервере, которого **не существует**, либо указан **неверный** `url`, что привело к 404 ошибке `net::ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.
- `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`, `Uncaught` - означает выброшенное исключение(ошибка), не была "поймана"(обработана), с помощью конструкции `try-catch`. Она говорит, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к несуществующей(`is not defined`) переменной `jQuery`. Скорее всего эта ошибка была вызвана тем, что у вас jQuery подключается **после** скрипта, в котором вызывается `jQuery`.
- `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`: вы подключили JavaScript файл `bootstrap`, но подключили его **до** `jQuery`, и в JavaScript файле `bootstrap` сработал конструкция `try-catch` и выбросила вам исключение, о том что `jQuery` должен быть подключен **до** `bootstrap` JavaScript файла. (Так же `try-catch` выдала вам сообщение об ошибке, которое может изменяться, а может быть и по умолчанию).
- `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`: Уже описывал **выше**.
- `Uncaugth TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined`: в данном случае скрипт пытается обратиться к объекту `foo` и получить его параметр `fn`, вот так: `foo.fn`, скорее всего это опять же из-за порядка подключения js файлов, именно из-за того, что библиотека daterangepicker использует `jQuery`, но `jQuery` не был подключен **до** текущего скрипта, что скорее всего привело объект `foo` как неопределенный `undefined`.
- `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`: Уже описывал **выше**.
- `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`: Уже описывал **выше**.

**Внимательно** посмотрите порядок подключения скриптов. Браузер считывает **последовательно, друг за другом**, есть конечно *дополнительные* атрибуты для подключения скриптов([async и defer](https://learn.javascript.ru/external-script)). Попробуйте перенести подключение `jQuery` **выше** всех остальных скриптов, и посмотрите что случится :).

Comment: Уточнение - самая первая ошибка GET - она как раз на загрузку JQuery, Все остальное - это явно следствие этой ошибки.

Comment: @Yaant, Правильно подметили)

Answer (score -2):

UncaughtTypeError значит, что ошибка не была перехвачена в catch
TypeError —  название ошибки
ReferenceError -  подключается к библиотеке  JQuery.
И ранее она видимо подключалась. А щас файл с библиотекой либо недоступен, удалён, переименован